# Changing Type Factor to Numeric without losing "."

Tags: r

I am just learning R and am trying to sum two vaiables in my dataset. I have changed Hits and Runs to type numeric from type factor without losing any information with the exception of 4 "." values which should have stayed "." but changed to "NA". I've attached a segment of my code and a sample of the dataset

```
 gamestats<-read.fwf(paste0(dirdata,"Games_Plus.dat"), width= widths, col.names = colNames, na.strings = ".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
gamestats$Hits <- as.numeric(as.character(gamestats$Hits))
gamestats$Runs <- as.numeric(as.character(gamestats$Runs))

6-19 Peaches      8  3 Complete
6-20 Peaches     10  5 Complete
6-23 Plains       3  4 Complete
6-24 Plains       7  2 Complete
6-25 Plains       12  8 Complete
6-30 Gilroy        .  . No Data
7-1  Gilroy        .  . No Data
7-4  Sacramento   15  9 Complete
7-4  Sacramento   10 10 Complete
7-5  Sacramento    2  3 Complete
```

Comment: `.` would be stored as a string and r doesn't support vectors with multiple types (strings and numeric in your case)

Comment: That makes sense. So then is there a way to specify a mising data value that would be acceptable in a numeric type?  I've removed the "na.strings= "."" from my code but appear to have the same results. The four obs are still 'NA'

Comment: I would guess that your na string is actually `' .'` not `'.'` since you are reading a fixed-width file. you could try adding `strip.white = TRUE` to `read.fwf`